# Recursive function in perl

Tags: perl, recursion

I have a file like

```
abc->bcd, efg, hij
bcd->ijk, lmn, ipl
efg->kfg, iop, nkl
lmn->opq, stv, imn
```

the nested output should be created from this like

```
abc
 bcd
  ijk
  lmn
    opq
    stv
    imn
    ipl
 efg
   kfg
   iop
   nkl
 hij
```

I am not very sure how to handle this in perl with recursive function to find any level of nesting. Anyone's help much appreciated.

I have tried with following code, but it gives only one level

```
my $k = 0;
while ($k <=$#array1)
{
 if ($array1[$k]=~m/(.[^->]*)->(.[^\n]*)/)
 {
   $val = $1;
   $val1 = $2;
   push @check, $val;
   print $val;
   my @array2=split /,/,$val1;
   foreach my $newid (@array2)
    {
    push @check1, $newid;
    print $newid, "\n";
    }
 }
 $k++;
```

}

Comment: provide the code written so for, to help you in this regard

Answer (score 4):

It's another directed graph! They seem popular recently

You need the [`Graph`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Graph) module, which will allow you to build a tree of *edges* and *vertices* (nodes and connections) and then traverse it to obtain your printout

This program does exactly that with your sample data. Once the graph is built, I test whether it's cyclic to avoid an endless loop and then call my recursive subroutine `print_vertex` for all source vertices

A source vertex is one that has *successors* but no *predecessors* (children but no parent). So it's a root of the tree. I've used a `for` loop in case the data has more than one root, but your data has only one such vertex: `abc`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Graph;

my $g = Graph->new(directed => 1);

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ($from, @to) = /[^\s>,-]+/g;
    $g->add_edge($from, $_) for @to;
}

if ( my @cycle = $g->find_a_cycle ) {
    die sprintf "Graph contains a cycle: %s\n", join(' >> ', @cycle, $cycle[0]);
}

print_vertex($_) for $g->source_vertices;


sub print_vertex {
    my ($v, $indent) = (@_, 0);
    printf "%s%s\n", '  ' x $indent, $v;
    print_vertex($_, $indent+1) for $g->successors($v);
}


__DATA__
abc->bcd, efg, hij
bcd->ijk, lmn, ipl
efg->kfg, iop, nkl
lmn->opq, stv, imn
```

#### output

```
abc
  efg
    iop
    kfg
    nkl
  bcd
    lmn
      stv
      opq
      imn
    ijk
    ipl
  hij
```

Comment: Thank you very much Borodin, when I try this, the order has changed in the output...can you help me on how to retain the orders?

Comment: @Senthil the 1st thought that comes to mind is adding weights to the edges.

Comment: @Senthil: Is that an essential requirement? It's achievable by using references to arrays for each vertex instead of simple strings. Or, if it's acceptable just to present the nodes in alphabetical order rather than the order in which they appear in the input data, you could just add a `sort` to the `print_vertex` subroutine

Comment: @Borodin, Can you help me on making this into an order, I am trying to achieve but couldn't... your help much apprecaited

Answer (score 1):

> ... when I try this, the order has changed in the output...can you
>   help me on how to retain the orders?

Recursive solution in pure Perl sans module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %children;
my $patriarch;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($parent, @children) = split /[->, ]+/;
    $children{$parent} = \@children;
    $patriarch = $parent unless defined $patriarch;
}

sub print_family {
    my ($parent, $indentation) = (@_, '');

    print($indentation, $parent, "\n");

    if (exists($children{$parent})) {
        foreach my $child (@{$children{$parent}}) {
            &print_family($child, $indentation . "\t");
        }
    }
}

&print_family($patriarch)

__DATA__
abc->bcd, efg, hij
bcd->ijk, lmn, ipl
efg->kfg, iop, nkl
lmn->opq, stv, imn
```

Produces:

```
abc
    bcd
        ijk
        lmn
            opq
            stv
            imn
        ipl
    efg
        kfg
        iop
        nkl
    hij
```